# why does vim insert a range when we press a number before pressing colon to go to command line mode?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line

I was trying to make a mapping to run a command that takes a count, something like the following:

```
nnoremap gb :execute('buffer ' . v:count)<CR>
```

When I run the mapping, I see the following error:

> E481, No range allowed

After checking [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13831705/6064933), I find it is because vim will insert a range automatically if we press a number before pressing colon `:` to enter command line.

Is there documentation on this behavior? Can I disable it by default?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure about documentation, but this can be useful to say `5:normal! Somecommands`, or some such (I don’t use it often, but I can imagine a situation in which it’s easier than typing the corresponding range myself).

As for disabling it, use the old visual-mapping trick:

```
nnoremap gb :<C-u>...
```

Comment: I am still learning to write vim script. The vim error in this case is hard to figure out, IMO. The `Ctrl-U` trick is neat and solves the problem.